# Compile each SASS file with Gulp, creating multiple CSS files

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I have the need to compile a SASS file to a CSS file when saved, without having to compile every SASS file to a single CSS file.

I need the ability to:
- Run a 'watch' on a directory
- If a file is saved, a CSS of it's name is created. Example: 'main.scss' compiles to 'main.css'. 
- It should not compile every single SASS if it doesn't need to.

The goal is to optimize the development process to avoid compiling every single SASS file in a directory when 'watching'.

My current SASS task looks a bit like this and results in a single CSS file:

```
//Compile Sass
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/scss/styles.scss')
    .pipe(plugins.sass({ includePaths : [paths.sass], style: 'compressed'})
    .pipe(plugins.autoprefixer('last 2 version'))
    .pipe(plugins.rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(plugins.minifyCss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'));
});
```

Comment: This will probably not answer your whole question, but have a look at this Gulp recipe. It coves generating one file per folder instead of one file altogether. https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/running-task-steps-per-folder.md

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `gulp-changed` is what you're looking for:
https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-changed

You add it as a dependency with `npm install --save-dev gulp-changed` and plug it into your gulpfile. From the gulp-changed ReadMe:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var changed = require('gulp-changed');
var ngAnnotate = require('gulp-ng-annotate'); // just as an example

var SRC = 'src/*.js';
var DEST = 'dist';

gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src(SRC)
        .pipe(changed(DEST))
        // ngAnnotate will only get the files that
        // changed since the last time it was run
        .pipe(ngAnnotate())
       .pipe(gulp.dest(DEST));
});
```

Comment: Please writeout the answer or explain how gulp-change works. The information you are linking to could disappear which would make your answer useless in the future.